# Convert a Point (or PointLike) to LngLat object

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I have a mapbox map, and I want to add a fixed marker. With "fixed" I mean something that is in `absolute` so fixed respect of the map div container.

Example:

```
(0,0)         (200,0)
+-------------+
|             |
|             |
|             |
|      *      |
|             |
|             |
|             |
+-------------+
(0,300)       (200, 300)
```

In that case the marker * is at the center of the map so to place it I can use:

```css
.marker {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%
}
```

and then use [`getCenter()`](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/geography/#lnglatbounds#getcenter):

```js
const lngLatObj = map.getCenter()
```

but if I want the marker not in the center but for example at 20% left and 90% top?

```
(0,0)         (200,0)
+-------------+
|             |
|             |
|             |
|             |
|             |
|             |
| *           |
+-------------+
(0,300)       (200, 300)
```

Here you can see the map container and the marker `*` on that map.

suppose I have the pixel coordinates of `*`, how can I find the longitude and latitude of that point?

I imagine something like:

```js
const x = 40
const y = 270
const point = new mapboxgl.Point(x, y)
const lngLat = point.??
```

I didn't have mouse or touch events. The point is fixed but user can zoom and pan the map.

With *marker* I mean not a mapbox `Marker` but a simple div element.

Thanks very much

---

[here](https://bsmco.csb.app/) a reproducible example

Comment: https://github.com/manuelbieh/geolib#readme This might help you. You can find the function you need and check the implementation if you need only that implementation without installing the library.

Comment: @CharanjitSingh I didn't find a function useful for me. Can you explain better your idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix using [geodesy](https://github.com/chrisveness/geodesy):

```js
const boundsNorth = new LatLon(bounds.getNorth(), bounds.getCenter().lng)
const boundsSouth = new LatLon(bounds.getSouth(), bounds.getCenter().lng)
const boundsEast = new LatLon(bounds.getCenter().lat, bounds.getEast())
const boundsWest = new LatLon(bounds.getCenter().lat, bounds.getWest())
const lat = boundsNorth.intermediatePointTo(boundsSouth, yPercentage).lat
const lng = boundsEast.intermediatePointTo(boundsWest, xPercentage).lng
```

Answer (score 2):

If you know width and height in pixels and the pixel coordinates of the point you can calculate the corresponding lat/lng values based on the percentage wrt width/height and use these to offset the mapbox's [LngLatBounds](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/geography/#lnglatbounds).

Depending on the desired precision a simple interpolation might do it:

```
var width = 200;
var height = 300;

var x = 40;
var y = 270;

var xPercentage = x / width;
var yPercentage = y / height;

var bounds = map.getBounds();

var long = bounds.getEast() + (xPercentage * (bounds.getEast() - bounds.getWest()));
var lat = bounds.getNorth() + (yPercentage * (bounds.getNorth() - bounds.getSouth()));
```

If you need more precision you must use spherical calculations, but the approach is the same.

Comment: Maybe `lat` should use `yPercentage` instead of `xPercentage`?

Comment: I tested it. It seems not to work. To compute the *lng* I solved using `bounds.getWest() + xPercentage * (bounds.getEast() - bounds.getWest())`, but *lat* seems always wrong using `bounds.getNorth() + yPercentage * (bounds.getNorth() - bounds.getSouth())`. Why?

Comment: what do you mean by wrong? I am not 100% sure how the lat offsets work in mapbox, maybe try `bounds.getSouth() - (...)` instead of `getNorth() + (...)`

Comment: That there is an important difference between `map.getCenter().lat` and `bounds.getNorth() + (0.5 * (bounds.getNorth() - bounds.getSouth()))`. I think that formula is ok, I also try  `bounds.getSouth() - (...)` but it's the same..

Comment: You should create a minimal reproducible example. I cannot investigate it from the given information

Comment: Here a reproducible example: https://bsmco.csb.app/. Thank a lot, I need help

Comment: Where in that code do you try to calculate the lng/lat of the marker and where do you get the pixel coordinates?

Comment: In App.js, line 75. As you can see the center coords computed using `.getCenter()` are different (lat is very similar, lgn not) from the ones computed using the code above

Comment: good to see you found a solution. As stated proper spherical calculations did it! :)